# C++ method returning any data type.

Tags: android, c++, ios, json

I am trying to implement a caching class for iOS and Android in C++. I am using nlohmann JSON (https://github.com/nlohmann/json) for caching.

I have a basic C++ class

```
class Cache
{
private:
 static Cache *instance;
 json j;
public:
 static bool fileExists();
 static Cache* getInstance();

template<typename T> void add(string key, T t) { j[key] = t; }
//template<typename T> T get(string key) { return j[key]; }
void persist();

string toString(); 
};
```

As you can see I implemented the 'add' method which accepts any type as the second parameter. This is an example I have in my Objective C++ class.

```
    cache = Cache::getInstance();

    cache->add("one", "test");
    cache->add("two", true);
    cache->add("three", 199.9);
//  auto obj = cache->get<void*>("test");
    NSLog(@"%s", cache->toString().c_str());
```

When I print the results to the console I am getting correct data. Now my issue is how do I implement the 'get' method that return any type. I have looked everywhere on google and cannot find a solution.

If I wanted to implement this in Objective C i would use (id) to return any type like below

```
- (id)get:(NSString *)key
```

I have tried this and I'm getting an error:

```
auto get(string key) { return j[key]; }
```

I appreciate your time.

Comment: C++ is statically typed, so a variable needs a fixed type. `auto` van deduce that type at compile time, not at runtime.

Comment: Why are you do not want to use a template method like this: template <class T> T getValue(const std::string& key) const. And to call it use this: std::string value = cache->get<std::string>("key").

Comment: Your suggested Objective-C "solution" doesn't work with primitive types or structs.

Comment: You can try `boost::any`. Don't know if objc week support this however.

Comment: @molbdnilo for Primitive type I would initialise the values in `NSNumber` object for example `[NSNumber numberWithInt:age]` 
@nightuser I didn't want to add another library but thanks for letting me know about this, i'll have  look at it when I have time.
@DanielJour Just read your message and it come back to me that C++ is statically typed, thanks for reminding me :-)
@AndrewRomanov I'll try your example, although I have the 'get' method implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nlohmann JSON provides great flexibility, the solution to your problem is simple, return an object of type `json`. Your function should look like:

```
json get(string key)
{
    return j[key];
}
```

Alternatively, you can try:

```
json get(string key)
{
    try
    {    return object.at(key); }
    catch (std::out_of_range)
    {    return null; } //If the key is not present.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response however it is seems to be returning the full JSON object back. What I am trying to achieve is that if I pass the parameter "one" as the key the method would return string "test" and if I pass in "two" it should return bool true and so on. It's not quite what I am looking for

Comment: That is strange because the documentation states that `operator []` returns a reference to the object with the key if present else returns null. (And I am pretty confident about this cause I have used the same multiple times). Anyhow, try using the [`at()` function](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a16a275d0201e9aedc87c933c764b8869.html#a16a275d0201e9aedc87c933c764b8869).

Comment: thanks, I have tried the example provided and seems to print the correct result. From the result how can I check the type? sorry for being a pain :-/
For example in Objective-C i would do this
`id obj = [json get:@"one"]
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
`

Comment: To get the type of the object returned, use the [`type()` function](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_ad81f3cedf09ccd70b2f3239d148c8752.html#ad81f3cedf09ccd70b2f3239d148c8752). Alternatively, you can also use ` cache->get("one").is_string()` or ` cache->get("one").is_number()`, etc. depending on what you want to compare it to. No big deal! Even I hit a few roadblocks when I started using nlohmann json, so I am glad I can put my learnings to use. :)

Comment: you're a star mate, thank you very much. Once I get the hang of nlohmann JSON things will be easier ;-)